# Insert with accent and latin1 characters

Tags: php, mysql

I have next table in my database of MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE cities ( 
    idcity int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment, 
    city varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (idcity), 
) ENGINE=latin1  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I will have around 8000 cities (aprox) and my query is right:

`INSERT INTO cities (city) VALUES ('Barcelona'),('Álava'), ('Cáceres'), ...` until 8000 cities of Spain.

What I don't want to do it is to use in PHP`utf8_decode` because I have 8000 registers.

In PHP I have the insert inside a string and after I execute the query. table creates right as latin1

How can MySQL recognize the accents of that cities?

Comment: Why are you using Latin 1 this century?

Comment: `ENGINE=latin1` WTF?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's absolutely no need to encode data manually (and please don't ever use `utf8_decode()` without looking up in the PHP manual what it actually does).

Most likely, you're failing to set the connection encoding when you connect to MySQL:

- In PDO, use [the constructor](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php):

  ```
    new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=foo;charset=utf8', ....);
  ```
- In MySQLi, [call `set_charset()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.set-charset.php):

  ```
    $mysqli->set_charset('utf8')
  ```

Now, don't type `utf8` blindly. You need to find out what encoding your app is using.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `utf8_general_ci` collation in SQL table for your `city varchar`.

Comment: how I have to implement it to créate table? could you give some simple please? I understand your idea